# What is the difference between stopbars and Intermediate Holding Position Lights?

Tags: runways, taxiing, lightning, taxiways

[image]

I know that **stop bars** continuously light red and stand at before taxi route joint, holding points, or at the runway entrance, but what about the Intermediate Holding Position Lights? How can we differentiate between the  stop bar and Intermediate Holding Position Lights with regard to function and location or color? I added pictures below; I am sure of the stop bar, but am I correct about the Intermediate Holding Position Lights? Btw; there is a definition for **Intermediate Holding Position Lights**: A set of three amber lights or full red stop bar are provided at intermediate taxiway holding positions.

Answer (score 1):

Intermediate position holding lights may be used at larger airports as an additional means of controlling traffic while moving on taxiways to give way for other surface traffic an a taxiway intersection.  Stop bars are used to provide additional identification of the boundaries of runway safety areas and ILS critical areas to prevent runway incursions.

Comment: Okay and what about the picture? Do you agree with the marking of holding light is an intermediate position holding light? Because it suits the definition above: 3 amber light.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that stop bars are used for stopping traffic from blocking ILS signals for traffic inbound on near runways, and intermediate position holding lights are used for holding short for taxiways.

Pretty sure your image has that explained already.